# 'mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am getting the following, while running 'mvnw' command.
How to add maven wrapper to a project?

> project_root>mvnw

'mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

Comment: you need to add the wrapper script to your project. you can follow http://bennet-schulz.com/2018/04/12/quicktip-use-a-maven-wrapper/ to generate your mvnw using a plugin.

Answer (score 5):

This issue plagued me for days, but the resolution was just too simple.
IF you're using Windows like me and the project folder has a **mvnw** file, instead of

```
project_root> mvnw
```

you need to type

```
project_root> .\mvnw
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Resolved it using taraki-maven-plugin, as mentioned here -https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/09/11/maven-wrapper-example/

```
project_location>mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem for windows.

1. go to control panel, go to system, select advanced system settings on right.
2. select advanced tab, click environment variables
3. now in system variables path add the path to your maven, /bin folder.

after editing it to include use

```
mvn -version
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the current directory you are working on has mvnw or mvnw.cmd files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).